# Why does my Dictionary Item keep returning 0? Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, int

I'm trying to grab an int from a nested dictionary. My code is as follows

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {
    let dfs = dict["forms"] as? [[String :[String:Any]]]
    self.init(
        atk: dfs?[0]["stats"]?["atk"] as? Int ?? 0,
        def: dfs?[0]["stats"]?["def"] as? Int ?? 0,
    ) 
}
```

However, the result keeps turning up 0. I know for certain that this is the correct file path, so why is it not displaying the correct integer? Below is the plist path I'm grabbing from. Any help into this matter is greatly appreciated.

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>forms</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>stats</key>
            <dict>
                <key>atk</key>
                <integer>49</integer>
                <key>def</key>
                <integer>49</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
<array/>
```

Comment: Use the debugger and see the value of `dfs` and `dfs[0]` and `dfs[0]["stats"]`, etc.

Comment: You could also add a `print(dict)` in your init.  It should print `["forms": [["stats": ["def": 49, "atk": 49]]]]`.

Comment: "forms": <__NSCFArray 0x170266400>(
{
    stats =     {
        atk = 49;
        def = 49;
    };

Comment: Seems you are hiding some other elements contained in the array, which may be the reason why your code does not work. Show all what you get with `print(dict)`.

Comment: The file is actually huge, which is why I only included the relevant part. I'm attempting to debug and I can see it go as far as read the atk and def but cannot validate the keys

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't abuse optional chaining like this. You basically begging for errors like this.

`dfs` is `nil` because you're trying to cast it to `[[String :[String:Any]]]` (a.k.a `Array<Dictionary<String, <Dictionary<String, Any>>>`), but its actual type is `[String :[String:Any]]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<String, <Dictionary<String, Any>>`).

If you had proper optional handling, you would have instantly noticed this error.

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String:Any]) {
    guard let let dfs = dict["forms"] as? [String :[String:Any]] else {
        fatalError("Failed trying to cast dfs")
    }

    guard let stats =  dfs["stats"] else {
        fatalError("No value for \"stats\" key.")
    }

    guard let atk = stats["atk"] as? Int else {
        fatalError("Missing or invalid value for \"atk\" key")
    }

    guard let def = stats["def"] as? Int else {
        fatalError("Missing or invalid value for \"def\" key")
    }

    self.init(
        atk: atk,
        def: def,
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the post. `[[String :[String:Any]]]` is actually correct because it is an array of dictionaries. Also I get the first fatal error **failed trying to cast dfs**. But I'm looking at the plist and don't understand why it would fail

Comment: In that case, when you used the code I provided, did you change the cast back to `[[String :[String:Any]]]`?

Comment: Yes, I updated it to reflect the correct one. The error still persists on the first guard

Answer (score 0):

So I've discovered the problem to my question. I'm reading from multiple source files at the same time and one of them had no `"stats"` dictionary.

I figured I had two options: To create an `If-let` statement to check for `"stats"` or to copy what I needed from the rogue source file and delete it altogether. I went with the latter, since that source file has been known to give me trouble in the past